# Round number up

Tags: php

For example I have a number 6.074 is it possible "round" it to number 6.08 ?

Comment: Yes possible. What have you tried Did you check sprintf function?

Comment: Less time to search google than ask here

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$a = 6.074;
$a = ceil($a*100)/100;
echo $a;
```

Output:

```
6.08
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do [round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)

```
<?php 
echo round(6.074,2);
?>
```

**Note :**

6.074 is always 6.07

Only 6.076 is 6.08